# Funky interactions of bbm and hyperref packages

Tags: hyperref, packages

I'm trying to use both the bbm (to write my preferred style of indicator variables) and the hyperref packages (to reference web URLs).

However, something strange seems to be going on whenever I use bbm in a subsection title. Any idea what might be going on here? Simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Model: Logistic Regression of $\mathbbm{1}\left[var\right]$}

\href{http://www.google.com}{This} is a hyperlink, and
 this\footnote{footnote} is a footnote.

$\mathbbm{1}\left[x\in S\right]$ is an indicator in plain text

\end{document}
```

The math itself compiles to pdf just fine, as well as the body text, for that matter.

However, a red box tends to show up somewhere in the document (which goes away if I click somewhere in the .pdf). Further, my compiler (I'm using the LaTeXTools plugin to SublimeText 3 on Linux which operates on latexmk) gives me the following warning messages, which I've no idea how to interpret.

```
./test.tex:8: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 8.
./test.tex:8: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\left' on input line 8.
./test.tex:8: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\right' on input line 8.
./test.tex:8: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 8.
```

If I exclude the `mathbbm` instance from the `subsection` title, the random red box still appears, but the warnings stop.

Comment: You can't include `TeX` code into `bookmarks` (that's what your doing with `\subsection{$\mathbb{1}}` effectively. You need `\texorpdfstring{\mathbb{1}}{something for bookmark}`

Comment: just to clarify--when the `hyperref` package is ?loaded?/?invoked?, `section` and `subsection` headers are translated as `bookmark`s (for, e.g., linking from a ToC--even though I don't have a ToC). So while including math in these headers is generally kosher, combining with `hyperref` engenders some parsing issues.

Comment: If so, then follow-ups: 1) Why does the math display anyway? Despite the warning, it built problem- (not warning-)free. 2) What's the `{something for bookmark}` bit? 3) What about this ephemeral red box?

Comment: Well, not parsing issues, just that TeX code can't be interpreted in a pdf bookmark

Comment: 2) Got it: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Problems_with_bookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unicode equivalent of `\mathbb{1}` is the character `1D7D9`, which has to be inserted into `\texorpdfstring` using `\unicode{"1D7D9}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,unicode=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Model: Logistic Regression of \texorpdfstring{$\mathbbm{1}}{\unichar{"1D7D9}}\left[var\right]$}


\href{http://www.google.com}{This} is a hyperlink, and
 this\footnote{footnote} is a footnote.

$\mathbbm{1}\left[x\in S\right]$ is an indicator in plain text

\end{document}
```

[image]

A visual list of characters and their codes can be obtained for example from  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

Comment: the Unicode bolded 1 is a nice touch.